# Jordan decomposition for non algebraically closed fields

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a (linear?) algebraic group defined over some field $k$ (not necessarily algebraically closed). For $g\in G$ we have the Jordan decomposition $g=su$ in the semisimple part $s$ and the unipotent part $u$. Now suppose $g$ is a $k$-point, then in general $s$ and $u$ are not $k$-points of $G$ (one sufficient condition for this to happen is that the field $k$ is perfect).

I recall having read somewhere that even if $g\in G(k)$ has no Jordan decomposition in $G(k)$, a power $g^n$ for $n$ big enough posses a Jordan decomposition with $s,u\in G(k)$. I think, they were considering a local field $k$. So my questions are:

1) where can I find a reference for this, or why is it true?

2) Is this true for more general fields?

Comment: The question is relevant only for imperfect $k$, so $p := {\rm{char}}(k) > 0$, and it is OK for $n$ a "big enough" $p$-power, not any old "big enough" $n$.  The point is that $g^{p^m}$ is semisimple for $m$ large enough, as the unipotent part in characteristic $p$ is killed by passing to a big $p$-power (since raising to powers is compatible with the formation of Jordan decomposition, and by inspection in ${\rm{GL}}_N$ any unipotent matrix in characteristic $p$ is killed by raising to a big $p$-power).

Comment: The condition that $k$ be perfect is not only sufficient for the validity of $k$-rational Jordan decomposition in all smooth connected affine $k$-groups, but it is also necessary. (It is easy to make counterexamples using $G = {\rm{GL}}_p$ for imperfect $k$ of characteristic $p$.)

Comment: @user36938. Thanks. This actually answer my question. Would you mind to write your comments as an answer so I can accept it?